# How can I find the path for a given file?

Tags: unix, path

How can I find the directory for a file?

In my Unix shell, I know how to use the `ls` command, but it shows just the name of the file. I need the path too. How do I get it?

Answer (score 5):

`echo "$PWD/filename"` will print the name of the filename, including the path.

Comment: isn't there a command like `filename x` to get the full to x?

Answer (score 4):

A quick search led me to [this](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/43661-how-get-path-file-unix.html):

```
find / -name "filename" -type f -print
```

or

```
locate filename
```

Comment: That assumes you know the name of the file, but not where it is.  Since the OP says `ls` can show the file, I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux you can use `readlink -f`; on BSDs `realpath` might work.

Comment: on OSX `brew install coreutils` and then `greadlink -f`